# Disabling a link using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to disable a link by checking if some condition was met using if statment in jquery.I have looked at other questions and tried these solutions

```
if (discussionPointsSize == 0) {
  $('#discussionPointsLink').preventDefault();
  $('#discussionPointsLink').bind('click', false);
  $('#discussionPointsLink').click(function() {
    return false;
  });
  $('#discussionPointsLink').data('disabled()')
  $('#discussionPointsLink').click(function() {
    return ($(this).attr('disabled')) ? false : true;
  });
  $('#discussionPointsLink').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    //do other stuff when a click happens
  });
}
```

but all the above solutions are not disabling the link.and just to be sure i tried `.hide()` and the link was hidden,so that means i am accessing the link right.so can anyone tell me what i should do?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by *disable*..? You want to prevent it from executing attached functionality, or change it's appearance, or both..?

Comment: I rely don't get why i got a down vote on this question.its clear and not duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here you should try `pointer-events: none;` in CSS. If the condition is true, we will add class `disable-this` for it. If not, we will remove class `disable-this`

```
if (discussionPointsSize == 0) {
  $('#discussionPointsLink').addClass('disable-this');
} else {
  $('#discussionPointsLink').removeClass('disable-this');
}
```

And we will define class `disable-this` like this

```
  .disable-this{
    pointer-events: none;
  }
```

Or you should do like this if you don't want to add anything to your CSS file

```
if (discussionPointsSize == 0) {
  $('#discussionPointsLink').css({'pointer-events': 'none'});
} else {
  $('#discussionPointsLink').css({'pointer-events': 'inherit'});
}
```

Comment: Yes!, It will work but does not seem pretty. Let us keep events out of `css`

Comment: The second statement has problem on pointer-events: as its not able to find it but the first one works perfectly.thanks

Comment: Yes. I forget to put pointer-events in single quotes. Now it works!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.If you want to disable its functioning.

```
$('.my-link').click(function (e) {e.preventDefault();return false;});
```

Comment: Add e.preventDefault() aswell :)

Comment: It will not disable anything.

Comment: i already sayed that this is not working as its clearly specified in my code

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).attr('href',"#")
```

It would not perform click and you should change color to gray

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way:

```
  $('#discussionPointsLink').click(function(e) {
    if(discussionPointsSize == 0){
       e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      //do other stuff when a click happens
    }
  });
```

I am guessing that you are trying to unbind the click handler to execute code, if this is the case then you can use `.off()` but you need to bind the event with `.on()`:

```
if(discussionPointsSize == 0){
   $('#discussionPointsLink').off();
}
```

Comment: As this is an `anchor` tag and `click` handler is used over it, `e.preventDefault();` should be always there irrespective of the conditions. One could do rest of the things using conditions..

Comment: @RayonDabre i feel i answered a wrong question actually.

Comment: Actually :P I was expecting plenty of comments below the question but many of them preferred answering it before knowing the concern..

Answer (score 0):

Try this.....

```
if (discussionPointsSize == 0) {
      $('#discussionPointsLink').attr("href","javascript:void(0);");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will disable the link and will make it a pure text, and if condition become false will make it a link again.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".anylink").click(function(e) {
    var discussionPointsSize = 0;
    if (discussionPointsSize == 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.disabled=true;
        $(this).attr("data-href", this.href); // Saving it if you want to regenrate a link.
        this.removeAttribute('href');    
        this.style.textDecoration = 'none';
        this.style.cursor = 'default';
        return false;
    }
    else{
        this.disabled=false;
        //assign href dynamically
        this.href = $(this).data("href");
        this.style.textDecoration = "underline";
        this.style.cursor = "hand";
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://example.com" data-href="http://example.com" target="_blank" class="anylink">Yo, Click Me</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm think have much ways to solution it, and my solution is add attribute **"disable"**, and **"preventDefault()"**, a some **"css"** code like below:

**HTML**

```
<a id="a1" href="http://vnlives.net">vnlives.net</a> | 
<a id="a2" href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$('#a1').attr('disabled', 'disabled').css("color","#ccc");

$('a').live('click', function(e) {
    if ($(this).attr('disabled') == 'disabled') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** https://jsfiddle.net/bnson/7hzvvwp8/3/

**Note:** I use jquery 1.7.2